# Is there a way to use OR in switch?

Tags: javascript, html

Just like the question says, is it possible to use || (OR) in a switch? Here is an example:

```
var color = "green";
var model = "ford";
switch (color || model)
{
    case "red":
        document.write("red");
        break;
    case "blue":
        document.write("blue");
        break;
    case "ford":
        document.write("Ford");
        break;
    case "yellow":
        document.write("yellow");
        break;
    default:
        document.write("purple");
        break;
}
```

I know it is possible to do this with an if else statement. I was just wondering if this could be done with a switch statement.

Comment: you can write `switch (color || model)` but i think you get not expected result :-) because this operator evaluted before, and you check `model` value only if `color ` have _falsey_ value like _false_, _null_, _undefined_ and etc

Comment: If SWITCH has the same working of IF then why IF is there? Simply NO for Switch, use IF.

Comment: seems like you need just split `switch` to two: one for color, second for model

Comment: Place this `switch` into a function and call it for each variable: `if (func(color) || func(model ) )`

Comment: I don't understand your logic at all. Why do you mix values for different objects: color and model? This allows mismatches such as: `color = 'Ford'` which is wrong (logically).

Comment: @hindmost you are right. I know understand why it makes no sense logically. This is what stack overflow is for. Asking and learning. I appreciate every one of you for helping me grow as a programmer!

Answer (score 1):

Aram's answer with a loop

```
[color, model].forEach(function(item) {
    switch (item) {
        case "red":
        case "ford":
            document.write("red or ford");
            break;
        default:
            document.write("purple");
    }
});
```

Comment: This is closer, but you should drop the part that emulates Adam's answer and revert to the original. But even then you have a problem in that the original would only execute one branch, but yours could execute two (unless that's what he wanted).

Comment: Good points.  Hopefully its enough for him to work through a solution with a combination of the options.

Answer (score 1):

It feels like you're trying to do too much with a single switch case, and that will make it harder to maintain over time. I'd suggest refactoring it into a function call. Perhaps something like this:

```
var values = {
  'red': 'red',
  'blue': 'blue',
  'ford': 'Ford',
  'yellow': 'yellow'
};

function getValue(key) { 
  return key in values
    ? values[key]
    : 'purple';
}

document.write(getValue('green'));
document.write(getValue('ford'));
```

Comment: This is best so far, assuming he wants to execute both. If not, you could do `document.write(getValue("green", "ford"))` and iterate the `arguments` object in `getValue()`.

Answer (score 0):

No, the closest you could do is something like this:

```
var color = "green";
var model = "ford";
var check = function(val) {
    return color == val || model == val;
}
switch (true)
{
  case check("red"):
    document.write("red");
    break;
  case check("blue"):
    document.write("blue");
    break;
  case check("ford"):
    document.write("Ford");
    break;
  case check("green"):
    document.write("yellow");
    break;
  default:
    document.write("purple");
    break;
}
```

Comment: And in this case it would be better to use if else. :)

Answer (score 0):

No, but different comparison in case expression:

```js
var color = "green";
var model = "ford";
switch (true) {
    case color === "red":
        document.write("red");
        break;
    case color === "blue":
        document.write("blue");
        break;
    case model === "ford":
        document.write("Ford");
        break;
    case color === "yellow":
        document.write("yellow");
        break;
    default:
        document.write("purple");
        break;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Not like you mentioned above, but this is how you'd implement OR in switch:

```
var item = "green";
switch (item)
{
    case "red":
    case "ford":
        document.write("red or ford");
        break;
    case "blue":
    case "honda":
        document.write("blue or honda");
        break;
    default:
        document.write("purple");
        break;
}
```

Comment: You could wrap that in a loop with 'item' as [color, model]

Comment: That doesn't do what he wants though. You're still only evaluating one value instead of two potential values.

Comment: This is not what the OP was asking for.